# the field name of OneToOneField field is append `_id` after the variable name

Tags: django

I define two models in django's model file:

```
class Personnel(models.Model):

    personnel_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    #...

class Settlement(models.Model):

    personnel_id = models.OneToOneField(Personnel, primary_key=True)

    #...
```

After run the `python manage.py makemigratios app_name`, I check the create table sql:

```
    CREATE TABLE settlement (`personnel_id_id` integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ...
```

Why the actual field name is `personnel_id_id` insead of `personnel_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django appends the `_id` for you in case of referential model fields.

From the [documentation of Database Representation of a model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation):

> Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name. 
>   You can change this explicitly by specifying db_column
>   However, your code should never have to deal with the database column
>   name, unless you write custom SQL. You’ll always deal with the field
>   names of your model object.

So, just rename your field to `personnel` and the `_id` would be added by django for you.

Comment: Does that mean i should named the field to `personnel` instead of `personnel_id`?

Comment: Yes.. That would take care of it for you. Just As you were typing the comment, I was editing the answer :)